# How could the WTI future price be as low as -40 on Apr 20?

Tags: futures, pricing, soft-question

Were there any known high-frequency firms suffer from it?

As the brent price stays normal, I believe that many algorithms would have recognize that price different as an arbitrage opportunity.

For a simple example, the brent price and WTI price almost never differ more than 50%, but now WTI price is 10 while the brent price is 20. The algorithms will start buying WTI but the price of WTI soon drop around 0, margin-calling all these algorithmic traders.

My question is, was the WTI price actually down to zero on Apr 20? Was it just a pricing mistake on some platforms?

Price chart: investing.com/commodities/crude-oil-candlestick

Comment: Yes prices were negative, see the linked question. You can be certain that some firms were on the wrong side of that trade.